# Passing dictionary as a argument to function to execute a query

Tags: database, python-3.x

I have a class called database which implements curd functionality. I want to pass a dictionary as an argument to insert in a function to execute a query.

```
        import pymysql as my
        class Database(object):
            def __init__(self):
                self.user = 'root'
                self.host = '127.0.0.1'
                self.pwd = ''
                self.db = 'premonition'

                try:
                    self.dbs = my.connect(self.host,self.user,self.pwd,self.db)
                    self.cursor = self.dbs.cursor()
                    print(self.cursor.execute('select version()'))

                except my.Error as error:
                    print ('Error: %s ' %error + '\nStop.\n')

           def insertRow(self,*args,**kwargs):

            sql = "insert into {1} {2}            
            values{3}".format(args,str(kwargs.keys(),str(kwargs.values()))
            try:
                self.cursor.execute(sql)
                self.dbs.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error during insert:::",e)
db = Database()
db.insertRow(tablename = "test", data ={'roll_id':'251452', 'name': 'Python', 'age': 28})
```

How to execute the query what I am getting is error.

```
File "database.py", line 72, in <module>    
db.insertRow(tablename = "test", data ={'roll_id':'251452', 'name': 'Python', 'age': 28})
File "database.py", line 25, in insertRow    
sql = "insert into {1} {2} values {3}".format(args,str(kwargs.keys(),str(kwargs.values())))
TypeError: coercing to str: need a bytes-like object, dict_keys found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know is separate invoke keys() and values() always get correct pair key:value, so may do something like this, to ensure it

```
template = "insert into {0} {1} values{2}"
keys = []
values = []

for k,v in d.items():
    keys.append(str(k))
    values.append(str(v))

sql = template.format(some_name, tuple(keys), tuple(values)
```

in other way may just this

```
template.format(some_name, tuple(kwargs.keys()), tuple(kwargs.values())
```

Also using args variable as you want maybe not correct if you want use the only table name. Maybe you must rethink this code.